# iterate through list and return value from nested dict by position

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of Dictionaries

```
meta_list = [
    {"id": 9, "name": "Tennis", "type": "SPORT", "url-name": "tennis"}, 
    {"id": 410468520880009, "name": "Live Betting", "type": "OTHER", "url-name": "live-betting"},
    {"id": 423407498380010, "name": "China", "type": "COUNTRY", "url-name": "china"},
    {"id": 613128412140012, "name": "September 7th 2018", "type": "DATE", "url-name": "september-7th-2018"},
    {"id": 643136938410012, "name": "QF", "type": "OTHER", "url-name": "qf"},
    {"id": 899076982160041, "name": "Zhangjiagang ATP Challenger", "type": "COMPETITION", "url-name": "zhangjiagang-atp-challenger"}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the value for "name" in the 6th dictionary,

```
for i in meta_list:
    event_name = i['name'][6]
    print(event_name)
```

I'm getting a list index out of range error.
How do you extract name 
"name": "Zhangjiagang ATP Challenger",
from meta_list?

Comment: `meta_list[6]['name']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do python indexing:

```
meta_list[5]['name']
```

Also note that python indexing starts form zero

#### Explanation:

1. get the sixth (fifth) element of `meta_list`
2. get the `'name'` key
3. Yup, you're done

Your code doesn't work because your iterating trough the `meta_list` then get the 6th character of the `'name'` key of the `i` dictionary

At the end the output is:

```
Zhangjiagang ATP Challenger
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain you step by step:

- you should first get the 6th element of the list `meta_list` through `meta_list[5]` (because the 6th element has the index 5, indexing starting from 0 in Python): you get a dictionary
- then you should get the value associated with the key `'name'` in this dictionary, through `meta_list[5]['name']`
- and you're done !

The solution is:

```
print(meta_list[5]['name'])   # Zhangjiagang ATP Challenger
```

Regarding your original code that doesn't work, the statement `for i in meta_list` iterates over each element of `meta_list`, so over each dictionary. When you do `event_name = i['name'][6]`, you try to get the 7th character of the value associated with the `name` key, which raises an error because 'Tennis' (in the first dictionary) is shorter than 7 characters. The error `IndexError: string index out of range` is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

'i' refers to each item in the dictionary. In order to access the value of the key 'name', use i['name']:

```
for i in meta_list:
    event_name = i['name']
    print(event_name)
```